# Unable to save data from anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, async-await, closures

I'm currently refactoring some code, and I'm running into a problem.

I am trying to return the value from inside an anonymous function. I played around with it a few different ways, and tried `await`-ing it.

Essentially I'm getting data about the request that's being made, not the data *from* the request.

**Here are some different ways I've tried working with it -**

```
const run = async (text) => {
  ...
  const s = personalityInsights.profile(req, (err, data) => {
    ...
    return data; // correct value
  });

  return s; // incorrect value
};
```

---

```
const run = async (text) => {
  ...
  personalityInsights.profile(req, (err, data) => {
    ...
    return data;
  });
};
```

---

```
const run = async (text) => {
  ...
  return personalityInsights.profile(req, (err, data) => {
    ...
    return data;
  });
};
```

I can give the full code, but I think this is more of a language specific problem I have, than a code specific one.

Thanks for your help,
Ollie

***Edit:*** This question has been marked as a duplicate, which I understand - but the solutions in that duplicate simply aren't working, and they aren't things I haven't already tried...

Comment: I've tried playing around with it, and a lot of my own solutions are the same as the ones listed, and it's still not working out - I'm not sure this is an exact duplicate problem

Comment: You need to make a promise for the data so that you can `await` it within your function